# How can I change which files Aurelia-App looks for?

Tags: aurelia

I've initialised aurelia with

```
<body aurelia-app>
   ...
</body>
```

The getting started guide (http://aurelia.io/get-started.html) says that this will, by default, try to load up `app.js` and `app.html`

How can I tell aurelia to load up main.js and main.html?

if I do `<body aurelia-app="main">` only main.js is accessed and the view isn't shown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you supply a value for the `aurelia-app` attribute, Aurelia will load that module and call the `configure` method that is exported by this module. This is explained in the documentation.

Your configuration must tell Aurelia which module to load for the app root. Here is the example from the documentation:

```
import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ConsoleAppender} from 'aurelia-logging-console';

LogManager.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender());
LogManager.setLevel(LogManager.logLevel.debug);

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .defaultBindingLanguage()
    .defaultResources()
    .history()
    .router()
    .eventAggregator()
    .plugin('./path/to/plugin');

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot('app', document.body));
}
```

What you're expecting to happen isn't the actual behavior. Setting the value of attribute points Aurelia to a configuration module that will point aurelia to the app root. In your case, you might want to do something like this:

`index.html`

```
...
<body aurelia-app="configuration">
...
```

`src\configuration.js`

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot('main', document.body));
}
```

And then `src\main.js` and `src\main.html` will be loaded as you expect (well, actually it will be `dist\main.js` and `dist\main.html`, but the files you're editing are in the `src` directory).

Comment: Is there anything in the [project files](http://aurelia.io/downloads/basic-aurelia-project.zip) from the ["Quick Start" guide](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start), that will prevent me from changing the default root component? I tried what the documentation says that it is necessary to specify another root component, but apparently there's something wrong with the `config-esnext.js` file because the new root component  `aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('hello'), document.body)` is not found when I run the application

Comment: These are the 2 errors  I always get : 1) `GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello 404 (Not Found)` ,  2)  `system.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello
 Error loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello`

Comment: Since you are using the quickstart, which does things a bit differently, you'll have to use `aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('src/hello'));`. You won't have to add the `src/` part in a CLI app or in an ap based on our skeletons.

Comment: Thank you Ashley. It worked! My bad for not having thought of that. Yeah I've seen that it's not necessary in the skeletons. I think I'm going to use the quickstart, at least until a new version of the skeleton that use a more "standard" version of webpack is released, which according to @niieani, it's on its way.